# I want to incorporate 'exit' inside a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, powershell, sh

I have a code that is running something from the shell script and after that run it ends up in this state as a root

root@(none):/testjob/test#

I want to exit this root state by running a command through the shell script to

arnavs@linux-machine:/testjob/test$

Manually you can just type in 'exit' command and it will exit back to the original shell but if I add exit inside the shell script it will exit the shell script itself and will stopping running the shell script.

Can you help me with a command that I could add it into my shell script ?

Comment: why are you escalating fully to root inside the script? are you starting a screen or something?

Comment: I am not doing it. I am running some tests which are developed by google and these tests run on uml and need full escalated root access. It is something which is done by the tests

Comment: A script can't make you root after it exits. Instead, the script is running an interactive root shell for some reason. The script doesn't exit until you exit this shell. Find out which command the script is running that is giving you an interactive root shell.

Answer (score 0):

Script lefts you as root? How do you do that?
Anyway, try to use `logout` from inside the script. 
However, not sure it will help at all, because I think you have some troubles with script and/or your system environment.

Can you tell, how do your script gets superuser in the first place?

Comment: I am running this 
if (( $NUMTAPINTERFACES > 0 )); then
  user=${USER:0:10}
  tapinterfaces=
  netconfig=
  for id in $(seq 0 $(( NUMTAPINTERFACES - 1 )) ); do
    tap=${user}TAP$id
    tapinterfaces="$tapinterfaces $tap"
    mac=$(printf fe:fd:00:00:00:%02x $id)
    netconfig="$netconfig eth$id=tuntap,$tap,$mac"
  done
  for tap in $tapinterfaces; do
    if ! ip link list $tap > /dev/null; then
      echo "Creating tap interface $tap" >&2
      sudo tunctl -u $USER -t $tap
      sudo ip link set $tap up
    fi
  done

Comment: You can checkout this link https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/tests/+/master/net/test/run_net_test.sh

Comment: running logout gave me -> bash: logout: not login shell: use `exit'

Comment: @Arnold In your script I see only two invocations of `sudo` and nothing else, which means your shell cannot have root privileges after running it.

Comment: @Arnold Can you tell me what `whoami` says about your login at that time? Run `env | grep -e '\(USER\|GROUP\|UID\|GID\)'` in your shell to check your environment variables.

Comment: env | grep -e '\(USER\|GROUP\|UID\|GID\)' -> Doesnt show anything. No output.
whoami -> root (output is root)

Comment: So basically I think I am in the VM i.e. uml environment